# WithinDistance in spatial indexing neo4j not give appropriate Result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

We are using **Spring Data Neo4j 3.2.0** ,and **Neo4j-spatial 0.13-neo4j-2.1.6** in a Grails Project 2.4.3

In UserDomain

```
@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.POINT, indexName = "junctionLocations")
  Point wkt
```

In UserRepository

```
    @Transactional
        Result<UserDomain> findWithinDistance( final String indexName, Circle circle)

@Query("START item=node:junctionLocations({0}) RETURN labels(item) as label ,item")
        List match(String a)
```

So when we run

```
    Iterable<UserDomain> teamMembers1 = userDomainRepository.findWithinDistance
("junctionLocations", new
                Circle(new Point(28.6100,77.2300),new Distance(2, Metrics.KILOMETERS)));
```

Then it give exact data 
but when we run

```
Iterable<UserDomain> teamMembers = userDomainRepository.match("withinDistance:[28.6100,77.2300,2.0]")
```

then it does not give any data but if we increase the distance to 10000 then it give data .

Actually we want to get correct data using Cypher Query. 
Are we missing something ?
Is there anyway to get correct data using Cypher ?

Comment: Could be that the default distance is meters. Or you have to flip  lat/lon. Not sure.

Comment: If the Distance in meter then , how should  this work 
 Iterable<UserDomain> teamMembers1 = userDomainRepository.findWithinDistance
("junctionLocations", new
                Circle(new Point(28.6100,77.2300),new Distance(2, Metrics.KILOMETERS))); . 

I dont think so problem is with meter or kilo meter

Comment: It works , problem is I flip lat/lon ... My mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem in Documentation of Spatial Repository

```
@Transactional
Result<T> findWithinDistance(final String indexName, final double lat, double lon, double distanceKm);
```

. In database we have corrdinates of Delhi and Gurgaon

**Delhi Latitude : 28.38 
Longitude : 77.12**

**Gurgaon Latitude : 30.30 
Longitude : 74.60**

So from my point of view , If I search

```
findWithinDistance("junctionLocations", 28.6100,77.2300, 35.5);
```

**i.e 28.6100 lat and 77.23 long and 35.5 Distance in km**

this does not give any data

But if I swap lat,lon position then Query give appropriate result

```
findWithinDistance("junctionLocations",77.2300, 28.6100, 35.5);
```

So If I am correct then in Spatial Repository correct way is

```
@Transactional
Result<T> findWithinDistance(final String indexName, final double lon, double lat, double distanceKm);
```